# Change font styles wrt @font-face support

Tags: css, font-face, font-size, webfonts

I know that most of the "modern" browsers supports `@font-face` in CSS. But there *may* be some exceptions. I would like to know if it is possible to change font size of some selector based on @font-face browser support. ie, I would like to set `font-size` of a `<span>`.

I want 20px if browser support @font-face and 30px if not. How can I make this possible? It will be great if this can be done by using pure CSS.

Comment: See this: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/font-face-feature-detection/.

Answer (score 0):

I think here you should be use **IE Hacks** and you can also read about other hacks [chrome](http://mynthon.net/howto/webdev/css-hacks-for-google-chrome.html)
and [firefox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/) to be able check versions and match them, but i wanna focus on specifiec browser - [Internet Explorer](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks)

So as i started to say, you can use IE hacks to match fontsize, example:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
 span{
  font-size: 30px;
 }
</style>
<![endif]-->
 <style>
  span{
   font-size: 20px;
  }
 </style>
```

Like I said, you can use firefox/chrome and other browsers css "hacks" to check version, and check supporting `@fontface`, I've not gave you fontface example since I don't have link and i perfer not make a confuse.

Hope I helped.

EDIT: I'm not sure if I'm clear then I would like make a fast point:

You can check each browsers (also each version) and see if he support fontface, if he doesn't you just use the same browser hack to change span font-size.